# Gutenberg Block Toolbar - remove button

Tags: block-editor

I want to remove all formatting buttons except H3 from the Gutenberg Heading Block. I’ve read through the Gutenberg Handbook and haven’t been able to figure this out yet. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try building you own custom block?